# Check if a value exists in an Array object in JavaScript or Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to check if a value exist in an array object. Example:

I have this array:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test'}
]
```

And I want check if `id = 2` exists here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var a = [
   {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
   {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
   {id: 3, name: 'test'}
];        

var isPresent = a.some(function(el){ return el.id === 2});
console.log(isPresent);
```

Comment: it works! but with this change: var isPresent = a.some((el) => { el.id === 2});

Comment: yes sure, i kept es5 syntax just for the example :)

Comment: @stiv You have to remove the curly braces or it will return an object instead of a falsy value: var isPresent = a.some((el) => el.id === 2);

Answer (score 7):

You can use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

If you want to just check whether a certain value exists or not, the `Array.some()` method *(since JavaScript 1.6)* is fair enough as already mentioned.

```
let a = [
   {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
   {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
   {id: 3, name: 'test'}
];        

let isPresent = a.some(function(el){ return el.id === 2});
console.log(isPresent);
```

Also, [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is a possible choice.

If you want to fetch the entire very first object whose certain key has a specific value, it is better to use the `Array.find()` method which has been present since ES6.

```
let hasPresentOn = a.find(
  function(el) {
  return el.id === 2
  }
);
console.log(hasPresentOn);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *find* method as below:

```js
var x=[
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test'}
]
var target=x.find(temp=>temp.id==2)
if(target)
  console.log(target)
else
  console.log("doesn't exists")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let idx = array.findIndex(elem => elem.id === 2)
if (idx !== -1){
    // Your element exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isExist = a.some((el)=>{ return el.id === 2});
console.log(isExist);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse recursively your collection and then you can find the match no matter how deeply nested it is. Beware cycles though. If there might be cycles in the input, then you will need extra measures.

```js
function exists(collection, pattern) {
    for (let item in collection) {
        if ((item === pattern.key) && (collection[item] === pattern.value)) return true;
        if (Array.isArray(collection[item]) || (typeof collection[item] === "object") && exists(collection[item], pattern)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(exists([
    {},
    {},
    {abc: "def"}
], {key: "abc", value: "def"}));
console.log(exists([
    {},
    {},
    {abc: "def"}
], {key: "abc", value: "degf"}));
console.log(exists([
    {},
    {},
    {abc: "def"}
], {key: "abcd", value: "def"}));
```